# Raphael.js responsive svg or div

Tags: javascript, canvas, raphael

I am a beginner in Raphael. I have this canvas
I want to make this `div` responsive. Is it possible to do it?
Actually I want to do that if caunting-line-video(image) changed location, I want to change canvas_zone location.

```
<div id="zone_canvas" style="position:absolute;min-width:640px;min-height:360px;"></div>
<div id="counting-line-video" style="padding: 0px;" ></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should be helpful. You give the minimum width and height of the canvas. Then set the both sizes as 100%. Let me know if it works.

```js
    var w = 900;
    var h = 500;
    var paper = Raphael("canvas");
    paper.setViewBox(0,0,w,h,true);
    paper.setSize('100%', '100%');
    paper.text(200,100,"Responsive window").attr("font","30px Arial").attr("fill","#333");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.2.7/raphael.min.js"></script>

<div id="canvas" style=""position:absolute;min-width:640px;min-height:360px></div>
```